# SBApplicationController issues (always nil | can't obtain logs)

Tags: jailbreak, theos, logos

I'm having a weird issue with a simple app I'm building using Theos.

I'm using latest Springboard headers (dumped/fixed them myself), latest **ldid** and **libsubstrate**, and I'm testing on my iPhone 5 (with iOS 7.0.4).

This is the (cutted) Makefile:

```
include theos/makefiles/common.mk

APPLICATION_NAME = Reboot
Reboot_FILES = main.m RebootApplication.xm
Reboot_FRAMEWORKS = UIKit 

include $(THEOS_MAKE_PATH)/application.mk
```

And this is the code inside RebootApplication.xm:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    vc.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    self.window.rootViewController = vc;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    id sbappc = [%c(SBApplicationController) sharedInstance];

    NSLog(@"SBApplicationController: %@",sbappc);
    NSLog(@"SBApplicationController: %@",sbappc);
    NSLog(@"SBApplicationController: %@",sbappc);
    NSLog(@"SBApplicationController: %@",sbappc);
    NSLog(@"SBApplicationController: %@",sbappc);

    return YES;
}
```

My questions are:

1) Why **sbappc** is always **nil**?
2) Why I don't see NSLog output in /var/log/syslog? (I see everything but this app logs!).

Thanks

Comment: I don't think your code is being called. You are defining a function but it's not being called by the user or the system.

Comment: It is being called, because view background color is red, and if I put in a UIAlertView it displays the message correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SBApplicationController is a SpringBoard class. As you're running your code inside an app (not SpringBoard) the class doesn't exist.

You probably want to make a tweak.

Create a new Theos project and select the "tweak" template this time.